# Base Class to use with ASP.Net Page and UserControls

Tags: asp.net

Is it possible to create a base class that can be inherited from an Asp.Net Page and a UserControl. I know that Page inherits from System.Web.UI.Page and controls inherit from System.Web.UI.UserControl so I couldn't come up with a base class that could be used for sharing common code (instead of repeating same code in several spots).

Answer (score 2):

True multiple inheritance is not supported in .NET. But you could create a base page class and place common code there. Then create a base class for controls which would have a (protected) property that would cast current page to the base page. This gives access from within a user control to the public properties of the base page class.